# PhpStorm "Cannot find declaration to go" with custom class instance

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

PhpStorm is my favorite IDE, I use it on a daily basis. Currently I work on a PHP project that use a custom PHP framework. This project and framework do not follow best PHP practices and do not focus on writing clean, readable code.

In the source code we call functions to get a new instance of a class. For example:

```
cAlert()->addError('...')
```

The function `cAlert` is declared on a PHP file included by the framework:

```
function cAlert() {
    return c('Alert');
}

function c($className) {
    return ClassCall::getActive($className);
}
```

`ClassCall` create a new instance or get an active instance of the class. Finally the Alert class is used:

```
class Alert {
    public function addError($error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

### Problem

While editing the source code, I would like to navigate to the location of methods. This PhpStorm/IntelliJ feature doesn't seem to undestrand this specific architecture.

PhpStorm cannot find declaration to go to for the `addError` method of the class `Alert` (but it can find of course the `cAlert` method).

[image]

### Question

I understand that PhpStorm cannot automatically resolve this method declaration.

Is it possible to configure the IDE in order to manually link, in my example, `cAlert()` with the `Alert` class?

Comment: Accordingly to your screenshot (#1) your `cAlert()` method returns nothing (`void`) -- that's why you see such "Cannot find declaration" message. Your **particular** code example can be solved by adding PHPDoc comment for `cAlert()` method with `@return MyClass` in it.

Comment: It was an error with my screenshot (updated). The `cAlert()` method return a instance of  `Alert` through `return ClassCall::getActive($className);`. But many thanks because `/** @return Alert */` solve the problem! Of course, that was it, how could I not have thought of that before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a PHPDoc right above the `cAlert()` function declaring which class is returned:

```
/**
 * @return My\Application\Class
 */
function cAlert() {
    return c('Alert');
}
```

Then PHPStorm knows which class to look up.

Comment: Same response that LazyOne. It's worked out well! Thanks.